# Passing parameters to IN clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, in-clause

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Parameterizing a SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause)
>   [SQL Server - In clause with a declared variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944511/sql-server-in-clause-with-a-declared-variable)

Hi,

I am facing problem passing parameters to 'IN' clause. I am using the below query.

Query:

```
SELECT Topics.Topic_Id  FROM Topics 
    Where Topic_Description IN (''+ @Topics +'')
```

This query works when the parameter has single value. My parameter can have  comma separated multiple values like : 'one','two','three','four'. But the query fails whenever there are multiple parameters. How to get over this ? Please suggest.

Thanks

I have to use the above as part of a stored procedure. I have to take the result of the select query into a cursor like below:

DECLARE cur_TopicIDs CURSOR FOR 
   SELECT Topics.Topic_Id FROM Topics Where 
   Topic_Description IN (''+ @Topics +'')....etc

In this case how can I use dynamic sp as suggested in other links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use any of the split functions from here:
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648

Comment: Above URL which led me to the url http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/comma-delimited-to-table.aspx solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a string of format `one','two','three`  as value in the @Topics.

EDIT:-
Then you need to use `EXEC sp_executesql` to execute your sql statement. The answer is properly explained in the link given by **spender** for your question.

Comment: You're sure about this? OP doesn't make it clear where the query is being assembled.

Comment: @spender - I have not tried this myself. But since its a string substitution, I suppose this will work. becacuse OP is already adding the first ' and last '. In between we need to fill it with a string of given format.

Comment: This approach would be vulnerable to SQL injection. The split function is safer.

Comment: @Martin - Aah.. yes. I think you are right. I did not think about SQL Injection.

Comment: I am creating a string of format one','two','three as value but it is still not working

Comment: @San - Check the link given by spender as possible duplicate. That is very much the case you need. I think when you create a string of said format too, you need to execute this quert dynamically using exec call.

Comment: But this select query is part of an SP. which goes like this - DECLARE cur_TopicIDs CURSOR FOR
 SELECT Topics.Topic_Id FROM Topics 
 Where Topic_Description IN (''+ @Topics +'')....etc