# Declare variable for IN condition in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table which you can also find in the `SQL Fiddle` [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e83241/12):

```
CREATE TABLE Flows (
    Flow_Date DATE,
    Product TEXT,
    FlowType TEXT,
    Country TEXT,
    Quantity VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Flows
(Flow_Date, Product, FlowType, Country, Quantity)
VALUES 
("2019-05-23", "Product A", "Inbound", "DE", "400"),
("2019-05-23", "Product A", "Inbound", "DE", "400"),
("2019-05-23", "Product B", "Inbound", "NL", "500"),
("2019-05-23", "Product B", "Inbound", "NL", "500"),
("2019-05-23", "Product A", "Outbound", "FR", "300"),
("2019-05-23", "Product A", "Outbound", "FR", "300"),
("2019-05-23", "Product B", "Outbound", "US", "200"),
("2019-05-23", "Product B", "Outbound", "US", "200"),
("2019-05-24", "Product A", "Inbound", "DE", "900"),
("2019-05-24", "Product A", "Inbound", "DE", "900"),
("2019-05-24", "Product B", "Inbound", "NL", "800"),
("2019-05-24", "Product B", "Inbound", "NL", "800"),
("2019-05-24", "Product A", "Outbound", "FR", "650"),
("2019-05-24", "Product A", "Outbound", "FR", "650"),
("2019-05-24", "Product B", "Outbound", "US", "450"),
("2019-05-24", "Product B", "Outbound", "US", "450"),
("2019-05-25", "Product A", "Inbound", "DE", "900"),
("2019-05-25", "Product A", "Inbound", "DE", "900"),
("2019-05-25", "Product B", "Inbound", "NL", "800"),
("2019-05-25", "Product B", "Inbound", "NL", "800"),
("2019-05-25", "Product A", "Outbound", "FR", "650"),
("2019-05-25", "Product A", "Outbound", "FR", "650"),
("2019-05-25", "Product B", "Outbound", "US", "450"),
("2019-05-25", "Product B", "Outbound", "US", "450"),
("2019-05-26", "Product A", "Inbound", "DE", "900"),
("2019-05-26", "Product A", "Inbound", "DE", "900"),
("2019-05-26", "Product B", "Inbound", "NL", "800"),
("2019-05-26", "Product B", "Inbound", "NL", "800"),
("2019-05-26", "Product A", "Outbound", "FR", "650"),
("2019-05-26", "Product A", "Outbound", "FR", "650"),
("2019-05-26", "Product B", "Outbound", "US", "450"),
("2019-05-26", "Product B", "Outbound", "US", "450");
```

I use the following query to get data from this table:

```
SELECT Flow_Date, Product, FlowType, Country
FROM Flows
WHERE Flow_Date BETWEEN ("2019-05-23 00:00:00") AND ("2019-05-25 23:59:59")
AND Country IN ("DE","NL")
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;
```

All this works perfectly so far.

---

However, now I want to set a variable for the `IN` condition in the `WHERE` clause of the statement. 
Therefore, I tried to go with the following:

```
SET @country = ("DE", "NL");
SELECT Flow_Date, Product, FlowType, Country
FROM Flows
WHERE Flow_Date BETWEEN ("2019-05-23 00:00:00") AND ("2019-05-25 23:59:59")
AND Country IN @country
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;
```

However, with this I get error `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`.

What do I need to change in my code to make it work?

Comment: check solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723100/passing-parameters-to-in-clause-in-sql-server

Comment: *with this I get error `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`* This is an error for `SET @country = ("DE", "NL");` statement.

Comment: *I use the following query to get data from this table:* GROUP BY by all output fieldlist? Remove GROUP BY clause at all, but add DISTINCT. Or add some aggregate action, for example, `SUM(Quantity)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SET @country = "DE,NL";

SELECT DISTINCT Flow_Date, Product, FlowType, Country
FROM Flows
WHERE Flow_Date BETWEEN ("2019-05-23 00:00:00") AND ("2019-05-25 00:00:00")
  AND FIND_IN_SET(Country, @country);
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e83241/32)

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e83241/39

Comment: @Michi Grouping by all output fields causes excess sorting. See my comment to the question about this.