# SELECT VARIABLE - Dynamic command

Tags: sql, variables, select, sql-server-2014, dynamic-sql

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem bellow ?

[image]

I dont know how to put variable in where condition in a dynamic sql command .

EDITED

I put autofipe ddl right here

[image]

*SQL 2014 i am using*

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Comment: Please post plain text.  We are going to re-type all those lines.

Comment: Debugging is part of programmer's job!!  Have you tried to `PRINT @sqlText` before running the query????  If you have, it easy to see why your query doesn't run.

Comment: On the error message, there is value "038003-2" , but i am trying to look at the code snippet and i cannot find that value to any variable, what i saw is "006017-8 on line 6.. it is better if you will copy that code (as plain text) for easier understanding of the problem.

Comment: Also, if you want to debug and check the value of your @sqlText , you can perform select to validate the final value of that variable, before proceeding to exec command.

Comment: It looks like the cod_fipe column in tAutoFipe is datatype int, no?

Comment: cod_fipe its not int , is varchar , as i showed up above

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 ANO....` whats the datatype of `ANO` column??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this question has already been answered here:
[SQL Server - In clause with a declared variable [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944511/sql-server-in-clause-with-a-declared-variable)

Also, I'm not expert in SQL, but it feels like you didn't assign a value to @cod_fipe before using it, shouldn't that be `SET @cod_fipe = ...` instead of `SELECT @cod_fipe = ...`?

Comment: Doesnt matter if you do Select cod_fipe or set cod_fipe