# Dynamic IN clause with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building a dynamic SQL query in which I couldn't handle a condition where the `IN` clause is used.

Query:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(5000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ED.Name, ED.Age, ED.Phone, EA.Address FROM EmployeeDetails ED JOIN
            EmployeeAddress EA ON EA.EmpId = ED.EmpID WHERE
            ED.Name LIKE ''%'+@Name+'%'' AND
            EA.Status IN ('+@Status+')
            ORDER BY ED.CreatedDate DESC OFFSET ' + CAST((@PageNum * @PageSize) AS 
            NVARCHAR(10)) +' ROWS FETCH NEXT ' + CAST(@PageSize AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' ROWS ONLY;'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

When I pass empty to the `@Status`, I get a syntax error or on the `()` as it isn't valid.

In the above query whenever the `@Status` is `NULL` or `""`, I want the condition to be ignored. Any help?

Comment: Warning, what you have is *wide* open to injection. If you want to provide a list to your query, use a table type parameter. Don't blindly inject strings into your dynamic statement either, if you "must" use dynamic SQL (and you don't here) **parametrise** your parameters.

Comment: Use an inline case expression to add the condition to the SQL statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server - In clause with a declared variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944511/sql-server-in-clause-with-a-declared-variable)

Comment: @Larnu This will help me to a great extent but still what If my param is empty and i wanted all the records when that happens?

Comment: Use could you use a `NOT EXISTS` with an `OR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for dynamic SQL here at all; in fact your use of it here is **dangerous**. You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks. I strongly suggest you research the dangers of such a fatal vulnerability. SQLK Injection is a problem that has existed for decades and there is *no excuse* to writing such code any more; ignorance is not an excuse when so many companies have been named and shamed over the last 15 years for such *badly* written code resulting in huge numbers of data breaches.

Anyway, onto the answer. One method would be to use a table type parameter. I define a `table` variable here, but if this is a call from an application you'll need to look into creating and using a TVP:

```sql
SELECT ED.Name,
       ED.Age,
       ED.Phone,
       EA.Address
FROM dbo.EmployeeDetails ED
     JOIN dbo.EmployeeAddress EA ON EA.EmpId = ED.EmpID
WHERE ED.Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'
  AND (EA.Status IN (SELECT Status FROM @Statuses)
   OR  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Statuses)
ORDER BY ED.CreatedDate DESC
OFFSET @PageNum * @PageSize ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Alternertively, if you are passing a delimited string for your list (which it seem you are) you could use a string splitter and split the value. This *assumes* you are using a fully supported version of SQL Server (if not, look into an **inline** user defined table value string splitter) and the value is comma (`,`) delimited.

```sql
SELECT ED.Name,
       ED.Age,
       ED.Phone,
       EA.Address
FROM dbo.EmployeeDetails ED
     JOIN dbo.EmployeeAddress EA ON EA.EmpId = ED.EmpID
WHERE ED.Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'
  AND (EA.Status IN (SELECT SS.[value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Status,',') SS)
   OR  @Status IS NULL)
ORDER BY ED.CreatedDate DESC
OFFSET @PageNum * @PageSize ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: Perfect, Works well. I'll take all the suggestions given. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```sql
Declare @SQL NVARCHAR(5000)


SET @SQL = 'Select ED.Name, ED.Age, ED.Phone, EA.Address FROM EmployeeDetails ED JOIN
            EmployeeAddress EA ON EA.EmpId = ED.EmpID WHERE
            ED.Name LIKE ''%'+@Name+'%'' AND
            (ISNULL(@Status, '''')= '''' OR EA.Status IN (@Status))
            ORDER BY ED.CreatedDate DESC OFFSET ' + CAST((@PageNum * @PageSize) AS 
            NVARCHAR(10)) +' ROWS FETCH NEXT ' + CAST(@PageSize AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' ROWS 
            ONLY;'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Status NVARCHAR(MAX)', @Status
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(5000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ED.Name, ED.Age, ED.Phone, EA.Address FROM EmployeeDetails
ED JOIN
            EmployeeAddress EA ON EA.EmpId = ED.EmpID WHERE
            ED.Name LIKE ''%'+@Name+'%'' AND
            1 = Case 
            When (ISNULL('+@Status+', '''')= '''' Then 1
            Else EA.Status IN ('+@Status+')
            ORDER BY ED.CreatedDate DESC OFFSET ' + CAST((@PageNum * @PageSize) AS 
            NVARCHAR(10)) +' ROWS FETCH NEXT ' + CAST(@PageSize AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' ROWS ONLY;'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like this:

```
IIF(@Status IS NULL OR @Status = '', '1=1', ' EA.Status = ''' + @Status + ''' ')
```

Your code could look like this:

```
Declare @SQL VARCHAR(5000)

SET @SQL = '
    Select ED.Name, ED.Age, ED.Phone, EA.Address 
    FROM EmployeeDetails ED 
    JOIN EmployeeAddress EA ON EA.EmpId = ED.EmpID 
    WHERE
        ED.Name LIKE ''%'+@Name+'%'' AND
        IIF(@Status IS NULL OR @Status = '', '1=1', ' EA.Status = ''' + @Status + ''' ')
    ORDER BY ED.CreatedDate DESC OFFSET ' + CAST((@PageNum * @PageSize) AS NVARCHAR(10)) +' ROWS FETCH NEXT ' + CAST(@PageSize AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' ROWS ONLY;'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```